# SAP CP TMS throwing error - 'Failed to get deployment log messages for the process'

Tags: sap-cloud-platform, sap-cloud-sdk, sap-cloud-foundry

We are working on a project which is based on SAP CP Cloud Foundry.

Recently, we have worked on a POC to integrate CLoud Foundry with SAP CP Transport Management service using a free trial account.
We created a basic landscape in Transport Management with one root node connected to two target nodes and tried deploying mtar(Multi Target Application Archive) file to Cloud Foundry using the landscape.
Although the mtar deployment in Cloud Foundry is successful, we still get the below error in TMS.

***'Failed to get deployment log messages for the process 28edb1a9-8887-11ea-aecb-eeee0a80a6c5'***

It looks like somehow TMS is unable to communicate with Cloud Foundry.
Due to the above error, deployment status in TMS shows 'Fatal' despite the fact that the corresponding deployment in CloudFoundry is successful.

We have been working on the TMS service for 2-3 weeks now but getting the aforementioned error only since last week.
It was all working fine before.

Since we are using a trial account for the TMS service, not sure if that can be a reason for the error.

Appreciate if someone can guide us here to resolve this issue.

Please find the logs captured in Transport Management service.

Action ID: 21,470

Type: I

Node: devcf

User: 62881a80-ef10-46e2-806c-13fd04c2747a

Display user: IMPORT_SCHEDULER

Start time: 4/29/20 8:00 AM

End time: 4/29/20 8:29 AM

Overall Action Status: 12

Messages:

ID  Created At  Hash    Message ID  Message Severity
- Transport Request "test-release-v4.5.4"; ID: 14,097; Status: 12
21787   2020-04-29 08:29:14.6   F40D84CE9840F71E015D8D78FD6939F7

IMPORT_END_EXCEPTION    Import failed with an exception for transport request 'test-release-v4.5.4' (id: 14097) at Apr-29-2020 08:29:14 GMT, details: 'Failed to get deployment log messages for the process aee6edba-89ef-11ea-92a1-eeee0a8d21fb'  F
21786   2020-04-29 08:29:14.597 96EABE5D919D97D4C81E2F6E4AC5FCCB

ENTITY_END_EXCEPTION    Deployment failed for entity '14094 - Ledify_Test_MTA_POC.mtar' (id: 14101) at Apr-29-2020 08:29:14 GMT, with exception 'Failed to get deployment log messages for the process aee6edba-89ef-11ea-92a1-eeee0a8d21fb'    F
21767   2020-04-29 08:02:04.109 A07412A5B0EADC4B3E1BDD522AA7762E

DEPLOYMENT_STARTED  Deployment started. Process id: aee6edba-89ef-11ea-92a1-eeee0a8d21fb    I
21705   2020-04-29 08:00:09.702 C08D1FA8220359403649668F5DE12630

ENTITY_TO_DEPLOY    Entity to deploy: '14094 - Ledify_Test_MTA_POC.mtar' (id: 14101), of content type 'Multi-Target Application' ('MTA') and storage type 'FILE'    I
21680   2020-04-29 08:00:08.398 A2A3F429B7DFD06B37DDF876E28DD325

DESTINATION_DETAILS Destination details for node 'devcf' (id: 1), content type 'Multi-Target Application' ('MTA'): (name: 'AutocloudDevTMS')    I
21661   2020-04-29 08:00:07.219 8B8B799DAEDD4E93A76162F7B8256996

TRANSPORTREQUEST_START  Import (all) started for transport request 'test-release-v4.5.4' (id: 14097), at Apr-29-2020 08:00:07 GMT   I
21640   2020-04-29 08:00:07.047 B90C8C43B5945241ACAE45E30003FEDF

CONTENT_REF_FORWARDED   Content Ledify_Test_MTA_POC.mtar forwarded to node testcf as part of the transport request 'test-release-v4.5.4' (id: 14097)    I
21639   2020-04-29 08:00:07.034 D64010AE5EE9E4B45299453C1393242C

TRANSPORT_REQUEST_FORWARDED Transport request 'test-release-v4.5.4' (id: 14097) forwarded to node 'testcf' (id: 3, queue entry id: 14317)   I
21563   2020-04-29 08:00:06.002 9FA68DB7A9E1978D4BFBFA643A71E5F1

CONTENT_REF_FORWARDED   Content Ledify_Test_MTA_POC.mtar forwarded to node parallel as part of the transport request 'test-release-v4.5.4' (id: 14097)  I
21561   2020-04-29 08:00:05.978 96CED85009C6067532B84AD9355B2E01

TRANSPORT_REQUEST_FORWARDED Transport request 'test-release-v4.5.4' (id: 14097) forwarded to node 'parallel' (id: 7, queue entry id: 14241) I

Comment: To understand the problem better can you tell what TMS is? Can you also specify what version of SAP Cloud SDK is used and provide a stack trace to see what exactly fails? How do you build and deploy your `mtar` app? With the existing context, it's quite difficult to share any good ideas to try.

Comment: TMS is SAP Cloud Platform Transport Management service. Using this service, we are trying to transport and thereby facilitate deployment of the mtar file between different subaccounts in SAP Cloud Foundry.
We are building the mtar using SAP Cloud SDK pipeline (based on Project Piper). The pipeline ultimately uploads the mtar file to the Transport Management landscape which subsequently deploys the applications to SAP CLoud Foundry.
We are packaging multiple applications in the mtar based on SAP Cloud SDK for Java 3.16.1 and SAP Cloud SDK for Javascript 1.1.0. Updated logs captured in TMS.

Comment: Thanks for a much more comprehensive explanation and for updating the question with additional information. We'll take a closer look and come back with ideas.

Comment: I consulted with my colleagues regarding this but no one has experience deploying with TMS. From the logs, there's nothing SDK related so that we can figure out what might be failing in communication between these two systems. My recommendation would be to approach TMS and Cloud Foundry colleagues via their support channels and getting back to us if failure happens because of Cloud SDK.

Comment: Could you please retry to check whether the issue was resolved meanwhile?

Comment: The issue now has been resolved. We can see deployment successful at TMS and Cloud Foundry. Thanks all for the support!